# Update currency rates in database or file

Tags: laravel, caching, scheduled-tasks

i'm using laravel 5.7
i need to get the exchange rates and I want to create a scheduler and run every 5 minutes
Now, do you think it's possible to put the currency information in a config file or save it to a database and, of course, i think the cache could be, right?

Comment: I think you can keep the currency rate in database as its going to change frequently so changing config is not recommendable.

Comment: @MayuriPansuriya Well, if a user requests a currency exchange rate ten times in a moment, ten requests are sent to the server and ten queries run that is not good at all.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation the data will be **changed only in 5 minutes**. So when you get rates just store in the database and then get new values and cache them and give the user rates from cached information. But when the next 5 minutes left and you get newest rates then you must clear existing cache, store new values into database then get new values from database and store into cache and again give the rates to user from new cached content.

If your database getting grow day to day you must add additional logic to **not store millions of records into cache every 5 minutes**. I advice not to store dynamic content into the cache. Anyway if you want to cache you can use Redis, Memcached etc. **But keep in mind to clear and again store new content into cache.**

If you only get daily rates in every 5 minutes and not storing anything into database then you can use logic I have told above without database section. Directly save records into cache and clear when new rates getted.

And also add **index** to database table to get data more faster.

Comment: thanks, if i get currency rate and just cache them Without storing it in the database
no problem?

Comment: no problem. just renew cache when script run again. 1. clear existing rates; 2 store new reates; and script work well.

Comment: You can cache it in redis with time. So you can fetch rates from redis first if it null fetch from api and cache it in redis.